# [Python]How to edit nested array config values with recursion

Tags: python, json, regex, recursion, config

I have a config file that is made up of multiple nested arrays and dictionaries. I need to have a text command that can edit any variable. This is in Python 3.

Here is a sample of the config (json):

```
{
    "joinMsg":{    
        "help":[
            "I need help",
            "Type !help or !info"
        ]
}
```

The command syntax can be changed to something else but its as follows:

```
!config write joinMsg;help;1 'Try typing !help'
```

I figured out how to read from the config in this way but the way I setup the recursion means I don't have a way to replace the value.

This is what I have, arrays is something like joinMsg;help;1 with ; deliminators:

```
# reads from the config file
def configRead(arrays):
    try:
        arrays = configSearch(arrays)
        print(arrays)
        output = config
        for r in arrays:
            output = output[r]
    except:
        output = 'No array found'
    return output

# recursive config helper
def configSearch(arrays):
    searchRE = re.match(r'([^;]+);(.+)', arrays, re.I)
    if searchRE:
        output = configSearch(searchRE.group(2))
        output.insert(0, searchRE.group(1))
        return output
    else:
        return [arrays]
```

This code probably sucks (I'm not formally trained) and I don't know what to do from here. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason your are trying to do this recursively? It may be easier to do it iteratively first and then make it recursive after if that’s required.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be recursive, thats just the only way I could think how to do it. What would you suggest?

Comment: I would put it in a while or for loop and loop through my array until I find the correct value and then replace the value at that index with the new value. Like while the current index != the end of the array keep looking. When the current index == the index you’re looking for, simply insert your new value into that index which will override the old value. I haven’t interacted much with JSON in python so this may not be very helpful, it’s just what I would do if I were approaching a similar problem.

Comment: Thats almost what I did with `for r in arrays:` once I had the recursion build an array of array names. The problem is I can get the value but the path is lost unless I recursively rebuild the array from the bottom...

Answer (score 0):

So first, here is a modified `configSearch` that doesn't use recursion and also handles array indexes:

```
def configSearch(arrays):
    arrays = arrays.split(";")
    return [int(a) if a.isdigit() else a for a in arrays]
```

Then here is a new function, `configWrite` that will edit the config config and overwrite `arrays` with the new `value`:

```
def configWrite(arrays, value):
    arrays = configSearch(arrays)
    print(arrays)
    output = config
    for r in arrays[:-1]:
        output = output[r]
    output[arrays[-1]] = value
```